# C# Task.Run says System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise`1[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult]

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await

Good day,

I'm trying to get my value. But I'm experiencing a result that says, `System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise`1[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult]`

Here's my sample code:

```
public string GetStatusName(int empId){
    var status = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        return await myRepo.GetStatus().Where(x=>x.EmpId == empId).Select(x => x.status).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    });

    return status.ToString();
}
```

The result should be the name of the status, but it appears differently.

I tried using the `.Result()` in `return status.Result().ToString()` but it locks the UI thread so the fetching takes like a minute for thousand of records.

Note: The given method shouldn't be async as per requirement. so I put `Task.Run...` inside my method to be able to create a asynchronous request from repo

I'm using the `GetStatusName()` inside this code:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<EmployeeDto>> GetAll(){
    var employees = await getFromRepo.Employees();

    return employees.Select(x=>new EmployeeDto{
        ...
        Status = GetStatusName(x.EmpId)
        ...
    }).GroupBy(x=>new{
        x.EmployeeId
    }).Select(x=>x.First)).ToList();
}
```

I tried this one, to make the `GetStatusName` async and tried this code:

```
return employees.Select(async x=>new EmployeeDto{
    ...
    Status = await GetStatusName(x.EmpId)
    ...
}).GroupBy(x=>new{
    x.EmployeeId
}).Select(x=>x.First)).ToList();
```

But I'm getting an error inside the `.GroupBy(...)` saying, `Anonymous Types` & something like `Can't resolve symbol EmployeeId`

Any help please?

Comment: based on update `GetStatusName()` can and should be made async

Comment: You shouldn't be mixing async and synchronous calls, just do one or the other

Comment: You have async code, why is there a requirement to make it sync?

Comment: What is the actual requirement? The code will return invalid results the way it is now. `status.ToString();` will return `System.Task....`, not the results of the query. That method can be replaced with `Task<string> GetStatusName(int id)=>myRepo.GetStatus().Where(x=>x.EmpId == empId).Select(x => x.status).FirstOrDefaultAsync();`

Comment: Calling `GetStatusName` inside a `Select` though is simply a bad idea, async or not. You're executing *N* queries to get the names when you could execute just one with `myRepo.GetStatus().Where(x=>someIDs.Contains(x.EmpId)).Select(x => x.status).ToArrayAsync();`. You could also create a JOIN either in your repo or in LINQ so you won't have to explicitly read the names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The given method shouldn't be async as per requirement.

I recommend you change the requirements and go [`async` all the way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

In your case, ideally you'd want to avoid the secondary DB lookups by including the employee statuses in your initial employee lookup. [Entity Framework has built-in support for this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data), though it seems as though your database schema may need some work first (i.e., why are status names in a separate table, indexed by employee id?).

Since that solution is more detailed, let's shelve that for now and look at a second-best solution. You need to do secondary DB lookups, and you should do them `async`. Something like this should work:

```
public async Task<string> GetStatusNameAsync(int empId) {
  return await myRepo.GetStatus().Where(x=>x.EmpId == empId).Select(x => x.status).FirstOrDefaultAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<EmployeeDto>> GetAll(){
  var employees = await getFromRepo.Employees();
  var statuses = new List<string>();
  foreach (var employee in employees)
    statuses.Add(await GetStatusNameAsync(employee.EmpId));

  return employees.Select((x, i) => new EmployeeDto {
    ...
    Status = statuses[i],
    ...
  }).GroupBy(x => new {
    x.EmployeeId
  }).Select(x=>x.First)).ToList();
}
```

I would recommend this only as a temporary solution, pending a better database schema and/or ORM mapping.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your method like this:

```
public async Task<string> GetStatusName(){
    return await myRepo.GetStatus().Select(x => x.status).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

Comment: The given method shouldn't require to async as the requirement.

Comment: @AppleCiderYummy that doesn't make sense. In fact, the method *doesn't* need the `async/await` keywords. It can be rewritten as public Task<string> GetStatusName(){
    return myRepo.GetStatus().Select(x => x.status).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}`. `async/await` are only used to *await* an already asynchronous method, the don't make it asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

Avoid mixing synchronous and asynchronous calls.

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Make the method async all the way

```
public Task<string> GetStatusNameAsync(int empId) {
    return myRepo.GetStatus()
        .Where(x => x.EmpId == empId)
        .Select(x => x.status)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

and await it

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<EmployeeDto>> GetAll(){
    var employees = await getFromRepo.Employees();
    var tasks = employees
        .GroupBy(_ => _.EmpId)
        .Select(async x => new EmployeeDto {
            Status = await GetStatusNameAsync(x.Key), //<--
            //...
        }).ToArray();

    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    return results.ToList();
}
```

Comment: I already tried all of your suggestions sir, and no code red squiggle, but after I run it, already something like 2 minutes, but still no record showing, I tried to removed the `Status = await GetStatus...(x.EmpId)` and I fetch the records instantly.

Comment: When I checked the breakpoint, the code skip at `var results = await Task.WhenAll(...)` and didn't proceed to next codes sir

Comment: @AppleCiderYummy ok this might be something higher up. Are any blocking calls like `.Result` or `.Wait()` being called higher up in the stack? You might be experiencing a deadlock.

Comment: No sir, I removed the `.Result()` already before I make async all of the methods just like your codes. The 2 methods are already async and await sir

Comment: @AppleCiderYummy what about whatever is calling `GetAll()`? What platform is this running on?

Comment: It's only a `public async Task<IActionResult> SampleMethod(){ ... return Json(await ...GetAll());`

Comment: @AppleCiderYummy what does `myRepo.GetStatus()` return? Trying to narrow down what may be causing the bottleneck.

Comment: I understand sir, thanks for helping me out. that sample method is only an `public IQuerayable<Employee> GetStatus(){ return context.Employees; }`

Comment: @AppleCiderYummy but how does that differ from `getFromRepo.Employees()`? Wouldn't the status already be in the returned object from the first query?

Comment: Because they are from different repo class sir.